# Time evolution $x(t)$, $p(t)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, time-evolution

For the one-dimensional harmonic oscillator, if $U(t,0)$ is the time-evolution operator, why

$$
x(t_{0})=U(t_{0},0)\cdot x(t)\cdot U(-t_{0},0)
$$

$$
p(t_{0})=U(-t_{0},0)\cdot p(t)\cdot U(t_{0},0)
$$
and, in general, if $A$ is an operator, which is the importance of applying $e^{-iA}\cdot x\cdot e^{+iA}$?

In my notes I have:

$pU^{\dagger}(t=\pi/(2w),0)|x>=-mwx_{0}U^{\dagger}(t=\pi/(2w),0)|x>$

$xU^{\dagger}(t=\pi/(2w),0)|p>=p_{0}/mw U^{\dagger}(t=\pi/(2w),0)|p>$

$x_{H}(t)=x_{0}cos(wt)+p_{0}/mw sin(wt)$

$p_{H}(t)=-mwx_{0}sin(wt)+p_{0}cos(wt)$

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [Heisenberg formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture).

Comment: Your starting two equations are distinctly wrong/inconsistent. Discounting *m, ω*,  numbers, etc... and squaring and adding them should yield the initial Ηamiltonian, which should persists as the Ηamiltonian at al times. This normally happens with the similarity *U*s slipping out and, as functions of the hamiltonian, commuting with it and removing themselves. You must flip the time signs on either of these two expressions for consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide a reference for your given formulae/provide more context? In general, time evolution of an operator $\hat A$ (in the heisenberg picture) is given by $A(t) = U(t-t_0) A(t_0) U^\dagger (t-t_0)$. Now, the formulae given by you for the time evolution of $x$ and $p$ do not seem to be consistent with the commutation relations, whereas the Heisenberg time evolution yields (for $t_0=0$) $[x(t),p(t)] = U x U^\dagger U p U^\dagger - U p U^\dagger U x U^\dagger = U [x(0),p(0)] U^\dagger = i U U^\dagger = i$, where i have repeatedly used unitarity ($U^\dagger U = 1$).

As for your second question, a hermitian operator $A=A^\dagger$ always generates a unitary transformation $U=e^{i A}$ since $U^\dagger = e^{-i A^\dagger} = e^{-i A}$ and hence $U U^\dagger = 1$. What you wrote hence constitutes a unitary transformation on $x$ generated by $A$.

Comment: In my notes I have:
$pU^{\dagger}(t=\pi/(2w),0)|x>=-mwx_{0}U^{\dagger}(t=\pi/(2w),0)|x>$
$xU^{\dagger}(t=\pi/(2w),0)|p>=p_{0}/mw U^{\dagger}(t=\pi/(2w),0)|p>$
$x_{H}(t)=x_{0}cos(wt)+p_{0}/mw sin(wt)$
$p_{H}(t)=-mwx_{0}sin(wt)+p_{0}cos(wt)$

Comment: Can you please separate your equations somehow? Its barely readable … ;-)

Comment: yes, it's done in the question. sorry!